# PHP examples to replicate FeatureServer capabilities

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, php

I used [FeatureServer](http://www.featureserver.org) before and I liked it. The only thing I didn't like, though, is that it needs some other dependencies to work. That's why I want to try PHP instead.

I know that there are already ways to get e.g. geojson after query pgsql db with php and pg (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656177/postgis-functions-integrated-in-php-example) and [here](https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/1913855/)). I think they are good starting points, but I am searching some other good materials with good examples (not only the PHP tutorial like [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)) to start with.

Any pointers are welcomed, thanks in advance,

PS. PHP to be used with postgis+pgsql+mapserver+geoext+ext+ol

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're actually after? REST, different data formats import/export or something else?

Comment: @zimmi basically the common db get/post/delete/update using geojson, but also common ways to do queries like in featureserver

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for geojson support, I would go for builtin [PostgreSQL capabilities](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) instead of parsing it with PHP. It's available since version 9.3 and it works like charm with [Leaflet library](http://leafletjs.com).

You'd also probably need to do some routing if you want to build a RESTful app and you might find any of [these PHP framework](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-dependency-injection-container-performance-benchmarks/) handy.

Comment: thanks zimmi, but I need to make interactive queries, I know this is done in the client (for me OL), but afaik a need an script that makes those calls in the server side, that's why I was using featureserver+geoalchemy, and I think PHP could replace these ones.

Comment: Well you just make an AJAX call from JS to PHP, which queries the database and returns the result. Than you just update the map with the new data.

Comment: @Gery, I agree zimmi, [here an example where the webservice/ajax is a pure SQL](https://github.com/ppKrauss/ISSN-L-resolver), PHP need only to request the correct SQL function.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use Mapserver and PostGIS, you may edit the spatial database using WFS-T provided by TinyOWS add-on: [link to the docs](http://mapserver.org/tinyows/index.html#tinyows)

There is also a project called [dirt-simple-postgis-http-api](https://github.com/tobinbradley/dirt-simple-postgis-http-api) (former PostGIS RESTful Web Service Framework), but it's read-only. For full CRUD capabilities, you will have to create a backend service from scratch. OpenLayers.Strategy.Save and OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP work well with RESTful APIs. Pick some PHP microframework to handle the URL routing, and you will probably find a tutorial how to create such API with it. The only special thing about GeoJSON is treating geometry and attributes as separate entities, while in a database they are columns in a single row. You will have to split them (when reading) or merge (when creating or updating) and use PostGIS functions - ST_AsGeoJSON for reading / ST_GeomFromGeoJSON for writing. Also, remember that OpenLayers uses FeatureCollection objects for reading features (GET request) or creating new features (POST request), and single Feature objects for updating (PUT request).

Comment: @Michael Mackiewicz thanks for the reply, but I want to use PHP scripting instead, I think it shouldn't be that harder but still want to take a look at some really nice examples, just that. I know about TiniOWS as well as microframeworks, but I am not after those ones.

Comment: Speaking of the ST_GeomFromGeoJson function, be aware you need JSON-c support enabled for your postgis installation, otherwise it won't work (I spent almost a day this week getting it right, it was hell). If you don't compile from source, it should probably work out of the box.

Comment: If ST_GeomFromGeoJson function doesn't work, then geoPHP library can convert GeoJSON to WKT or EWKB (PostGIS raw binary) geometry format ready for inserting into PostGIS.